# Can't seem to run a bat file from a makefile

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, makefile

So I´m trying to automate in a makefile setting up the environment for a python project I'm working on. I've done this with make on linux before and I'm trying to do it with make on windows

I've set up make using chocolatey with this package: https://chocolatey.org/packages/make

My Makefile target looks like the following:

`setup-local:               ##Configures the local dev environment
    @virtualenv .env-$(ENVIRONMENT_NAME) -p c:\Python27\python27.exe --no-site-packages
    @echo "Installing requirements"
    @.env-local/Scripts/pip.exe install -r requirements.txt
    @echo "Now running .env-$(ENVIRONMENT_NAME)/Scripts/activate.bat to activate the virtual environment"
activate-local:
    @echo "Running activate script"
    .env-local/Scripts/activate.bat`

But I´m getting the following error:

`make -f MakefileWindows activate-local
Running activate script
.env-local/Scripts/activate.bat
'.env-local' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
make: *** [activate-local] Error 1`

I've also tried copying the activate.bat script to the root and run it with:
`@activate.bat`
But it also does not work.

If instead I use the line: `call .env-local\Scripts\activate.bat` I get the following error:

`process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, call .env-local\Scripts\activate.bat, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.`

Which makes me think that make can´t find the executable or anything like it.

Anybody had luck setting this up? I'm thinking now that maybe make can't change environment variables because of isolation but I would still like some input on how to run specific bat files

Comment: Maybe a typo? `.env-local` vs. `./env-local`?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Still the same output

Comment: Try using ``\`` instead of `/` in your pathnames - `.\env-local\Scripts\activate.bat`. Windows/DOS uses `/` as the standard command-line switch character (most *ixen use `-` for this), and `cmd` may not parse pathnames properly with `/`, even though programs that use the Windows API will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only using Windows shell commands, try adding `SHELL = CMD` at the top of your Makefile.

Source: http://gnu-make.2324884.n4.nabble.com/How-to-call-dos-batch-file-from-MAKE-file-td8643.html